# Dropdown in a celltemplate in AngularJS ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, celltemplate

I have a grid and in 1 column am only getting 2 values. Either closed or Open. currently it is a normal grid so the user can enter any value. I want to force the user in selecting either Open or Closed from a dropdown rather than him typing. Also i have that grid pre-populated. So already few rows will have values as Closed or Open. So i want the dropdown to be selected when the grid loads. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you can use `cell template` on ui grid